# How to check a series of columns and taking its values, checking the first, second and then seventh in each set of 10?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmRun_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim slastrow As Integer
    Dim srow As Long, dcol As Long, drow As Long, sws2col As Long
    Dim counter As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim myagent As String
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Phase 2")
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Commission Reference")
    myagent = dws.Cells(8, "d").Value
    counter = 1
    count = 1
    dcol = 7
    dwsdcol = 6
    sws2col = 98
    drow = 10
    swsdcol = 98
    slastrow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    swslastcol = sws.Cells(slastrow, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With sws
        For srow = 3 To slastrow
            If sws.Cells(srow, 68).Value = Trim(dws.Cells(8, "d").Value) Then
                dws.Cells(drow, 2).Value = counter
                sws.Cells(srow, 3).Copy
                dws.Cells(drow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                sws.Cells(srow, 71).Copy
                dws.Cells(drow, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                sws.Cells(srow, 65).Copy
                dws.Cells(drow, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                sws.Cells(srow, 67).Copy
                dws.Cells(drow, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                For sws2col = 98 To swslastcol
                    If sws.Cells(srow, swsdcol).Value <> "" Then
                        If sws2col > swslastcol Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        sws.Cells(srow, swsdcol).Copy
                        dws.Cells(drow, dcol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        dcol = dcol + 1
                        swsdcol = swsdcol + 1
                        count = count + 1
                    End If
                Next
            drow = drow + 1
            counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next srow
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use STEP in your FOR NEXT loop to hop across columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmRun_Click()

    Const REPEAT = 9

    Dim wb As Workbook, sWs As Worksheet, dWs As Worksheet
    Dim sLastrow As Long, sRow As Long, dRow As Long
    Dim sLastCol As Integer, sCol As Integer, dCol As Integer
 
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim myagent As String, ar(4)

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' source data
    Set sWs = wb.Worksheets("Phase 2")
    sLastrow = sWs.Cells(sWs.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    sLastCol = sWs.Cells(sLastrow, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print sLastrow, sLastCol
    ' destination data
    Set dWs = wb.Worksheets("Commission Reference")
    dRow = 10
    counter = 1

    ' filter
    myagent = Trim(dWs.Cells(8, "d").Value)
    With sWs
        For sRow = 3 To sLastrow
            If sWs.Cells(sRow, 68).Value = myagent Then ' BP
                ar(0) = counter
                ar(1) = .Cells(sRow, 3).Value2 ' C
                ar(2) = .Cells(sRow, 71).Value2 ' BS
                ar(3) = .Cells(sRow, 65).Value2 ' BM
                ar(4) = .Cells(sRow, 67).Value2 ' BO
                dWs.Cells(dRow, 2).Resize(1, 5) = ar
                
                ' copy repeating columns
                dCol = 7
                For sCol = 98 To sLastCol Step REPEAT
                    If sWs.Cells(sRow, sCol).Value2 <> "" Then
                        ' column 1, 2 and 7 of 10
                        ar(0) = sWs.Cells(sRow, sCol).Value2 ' col 1
                        ar(1) = sWs.Cells(sRow, sCol + 1).Value2 ' col 2
                        ar(2) = sWs.Cells(sRow, sCol + 6).Value2 ' col 7
                        dWs.Cells(dRow, dCol).Resize(1, 3).Value2 = ar
                        dCol = dCol + 3
                    End If
                Next
                dRow = dRow + 1
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next sRow
    End With
    MsgBox "Ended", vbInformation
End Sub
```